# Find the sum of coefficient of all the integral power of $x$ in the expansion of $\big(1 + 2\sqrt x\big)^{40}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

While going through certain question online. This question took a lot of my time.
Can anyone please help me with this question!!

Comment: This seems straight forward if you use binomial theorem.Have you tried using it?

Comment: @kingW3
I don't know how to attempt such question's.

But i have searched for "Sum of coefficient" and 
i know put x = 1 and solve
then you'll get the sum of coeff.
But I wanna know why ?

Comment: Do you know what is binomial theorem?

Comment: I only started learning binomial today itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is $\frac{1}{2} (3^{40} + 1)$. Let
$$g(y) = (1 + 2 y)^{40}$$
Sought for is the sum of coefficients of $y^{2i}$ of the series expansion of $g(y)$.
Now the subseries of $g(y)$ consisting only of even powers is obviously $h(y) = \frac{1}{2}(g(y) + g(-y))$. The sum of these coefficients is therefore $h(1) = \frac{1}{2}(g(1) + g(-1)) = \frac{1}{2}(3^{40} + (-1)^{40}) = \frac{1}{2}(3^{40} + 1)$

Comment: Bohm
thanx a lot :)